# Upload photo to facebook page of the timeline

Tags: facebook, api, photo

I made a small facebook application for upload a image to facebook fan page timeline.

I'm sending a image via `/page_id/feed` url and no problem, image has been showing on my fan page timeline. But image size too small.

I want upload a photo to my fan page timeline with a diffent way using `/page_id/photos` url and this method working. But at this time, image post has been showing on "Recent Posts by Others on MyFacebookFanPage" and not showing on my fan page timeline. And I, cannot share this image on my fan page.

I'm using this facebook perms : publish_stream, manage_pages, photo_upload

How can I post a image to the my fan page timeline without

Thank you,
Regards.